# Delphi program & Windows 64-bit compatibility issue

Tags: windows, delphi, 64-bit, compatibility

I have some customers/candidate who complained that my program doesn't work on their Windows 7 64 bit version (confirmed with screenshots).  The errors were strange, for example:

> in the trial version i am
>   getting a error message whenever i
>   click on \"mark\" \"delete\" \"help\".
>
> error msg is: Access violation at
>   address 0046C978 in module
>   \'ideduper.exe.\' read of address
>   00000004
>
> windows 7 ultimate 64bit.  i7 920
>   @2.67GHz 9gb or ram

'Mark', 'delete' and 'help' are just standard TToolButton on TToolbar.

The other example is failing to get a thumbnail from IExtractImage.

I have told them to try Compatibility mode but still doesn't work.

The problem is when I tested it on Windows 7 HP 64-bit on my computer (which I've done it before released it actually) it just works fine! So I don't know what causing it

Do you have any advice ?Are different Windows package (home basic,premium,ultimate,etc) treating 32 bit prog differently ?Are the newer version of Delphis (I use 2006) more compatible with 64 bit Windows ? Do I need to wait until 64 bit compiler out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: (removed ugly comment train: summary - it may or not have been a compiler issue, a hardware issue, an OS issue or a coding issue - in no particular order)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best bet in my opinion is to add MadExcept or EurekaLog or something similar to your application and give it to the customer to try again. MadExcept will generate log with stack trace, which will give you a clearer view of what is happening there.

To answer 2nd part of the question, 32bit Delphi programs work fine on 64bit Windows 7. I think it's more likely you have some memory management problems and the customer just happens to stumble upon them while you don't. Use FastMM4 to track those down.

Comment: Is there any free alternative ?

Comment: @Irwan You have customers and can't want to pay for madExcept? You need to start charging more. Think of it this way, if you can make your program better (so that it actually runs!) then you might make more money in the long run by investing a little now.

Comment: MadExcept is CHEAP for commercial use, and free for non-commercial use.    You could code up something using JCLDebug too, but if it took you an hour, and your time was worth, what?

Comment: @Irwan: you can easily build something using the Jedi libraries, you don't need much more than JclDebug to generate the logs and stack traces, then JclException to send them. Assuming your time is worth so little that E129 is worth more than a few hours work, you're set.

Comment: Will try JCL and madExcept if it's not sufficient. Thanks for all suggestions !

Answer (score 3):

Your applications is trying to access an invalid pointer. Changing environment may surface issues that are hidden in others. Check your application, and use FastMM + JCL+JCVL/MadExcept/EurekaLog to get a detailed trace of the issue. Some Windows APIs may have some stricter call requisites under 7 and/or 64 bit, but we would have to know what your app actually cals.

Comment: What APIs are you thinking of that have stricter call requisites?

Comment: In this situation I have no idea if is calling some APIs or not, it was just a general suggestion about what could be investigated.

Answer (score 3):

A free alternative to MadExcept is JCL Debug stuff. However it is less thorough and doesn't include the cool dialog box to send the stack trace to you via email, or as a file you can attach and manually email.

MadExcept is worth the money, and it is free for non-commercial use. You could try it first on your own PC, observe its functionality, and be sure it functions the way you want,  and then buy it.

If buying Delphi is worth it (and it is!) then buying mad Except is a no brainer.  But if you insist on rolling your own, JCLDebug (part of jedi code library) is also pretty nice.

Comment: JCL Exception dialog does include options to send the stack trace via email or save it to file.

Answer (score 1):

Give them a stripped down version of your app and see when the problem goes away. I am betting it is your code as I never had any problems with my (hundreds of) W7/64 clients.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet it's an issue in your code. The reason it's failing on your customer's machine and not yours is that your machine probably has the default Data Execution Protection (DEP) enabled (which is turned on only for essential Windows programs and services), while your customer's computer is actually using DEP as intended (turned on for all programs and services).

The default setting (which is compatible with older versions of Windows, like 95/98/ME), allows software to execute code from what should be data segments. The more strict setting won't allow this, and raises a system-level exception instead.

You can check the settings between the two by looking at System Properties. I'm not at a Win7 machine right now, but on WinXP you get there by right-clicking on My Computer, choosing Properties, clicking on Performance Options, and then selecting the "Data Execution Prevention" tab. Find it on Vista/Win7 by using the Help; search for Data Execution Protection.

The solution, as previous answers have told you, is to install MadExcept or EurekaLog. You can also get a free version as part of [JEDI](http://www.delphi-jedi.org), in JCLDebug IIRC. I haven't used it, so I can't vouch for it personally. I've heard it's pretty good, though.

If you don't want to go that route, set a breakpoint somewhere in the startup portion of your app (make sure to build with debugging info turned on). Run your app until the breakpoint is hit, and then use the IDE's Search->Goto Address (which is disabled until the breakpoint is hit). Enter the address from the exception dialog (not the one that's almost all zeros, but the 0046C978 address, prefixed with $ to indicate it's in hex) as in $0046C978. You'll probably end up in the CPU window looking at assembly code, but you can usually pick out a line of Delphi code of some sort that can sometimes give you a place to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all previous suggestions, I'll add the difference in accessing Registry under WOW64 compared to Win32. If your application is accessing Registry to read or write some settings, you should be aware of this. First, take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page in the MSDN. On [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page you will find 2 flags that determine the access you get to Registry from 32- or 64-bit application. `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` is the one that you should use.

In any case, I agree with others about using madExcept (or any other similar tool) to be able to find the exact cause of your problems.